# How to sort an array in javascript, but save results in separate array

Tags: javascript

I want to sort an array of objects based upon any of those object properties. But I want the original array left unchanged. Instead, I want to save the sort order of indexes in a separate array.

```
var source = [
  {"a": 2, "b": 8, "c": 9},
  {"a": 4, "b": 3, "c": 7},  
  {"a": 1, "b": 0, "c": 6}
]

var sortedIndexes;

SomeSortOfSortMethod("a", "asc");

// result of sortedIndexes containing indexes to source array:
// [2, 0, 1]
```

Any ideas how to do this? I can't use the built in javascript sort method because it changes source. I need to just capture what the sort would be and save that order as indexes to the source arry.

Comment: Copy initial array and operate copied array ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var source = [
      {"a": 2, "b": 8, "c": 9},
      {"a": 4, "b": 3, "c": 7},  
      {"a": 1, "b": 0, "c": 6}
    ];

var orderedCopyArray = _.sortBy(source, "a");

// Defualt ascending
console.log(JSON.stringify(orderedCopyArray));

// Descending
console.log(JSON.stringify(orderedCopyArray.reverse()));

var indexesArray = [], leng = source.length;

// Descending array ordered
var reverse = orderedCopyArray.reverse();

// Get index
for(var i=0; i < leng; i++){
  var obj1 = reverse[i]; 
  for(var j=0; j < leng; j++){
    var obj2 = source[j];
    if(_.isEqual(obj1, obj2)){
      indexesArray.push(j);
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(indexesArray); //[2, 0, 1]
```

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Mmmmm honestly in my opinion this is a valid alternative answer. Using external library is most of the times better than implement on your own a new one.

Comment: Because otherwise questions will be "answered" with suggestions to use libraries and not real answers. Imagine asking a DOM question and just getting answers like "use jQuery", "use Dojo", "use prototype.js"…

Comment: Ok, I added an example how do it wi UnderscoreJS

Comment: I agree RobG that questions can't be answered by just saying use such and such library. But I do appreciate ronIDX taking the time to explain the process through.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because of the code explaining how to go through and figure out the indexes, which was the crux of what I was hoping to solve. So , thank you for that. So, I did make some mods though, cause the JSON.stringify was killing performance. I spliced the original array, thus making a new copy, but keeping references to the same objects. Now, I could compare object to object: much, much faster.

Comment: It may be informant to others out there if you did make that change, which ironically, would remove the need for underscore. So, instead of doing _.sortBy(source, "a"). Do: source.slice(). Then remove the JSON.stringify

Comment: I understand the slice() part, but not the object compare. I tried to compare directly Javascript Object, but return false always: [Javascript Object Compare](http://codepen.io/grimaldello/pen/yeRWJY?editors=1111). However feel free to edit my answer

Comment: Just discover this for objects compare: [Undescore.JS compare Javascript objects equality](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual)

Comment: Modified answer to fits _.isEqual() method. Dunno performance for this method

Comment: That's much better performance wise to run the isEqual. Thanks for updating that. I'm still using the obj to obj compare which is working. But either way is viable.

Answer (score 1):

> Make deep copy of initial array using `array.map()` and [`clone`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) and apply sorting function over `copied` array.
>
> The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.
>
> The [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array.

Try this:

```js
var source = [{
  "a": 2,
  "b": 8,
  "c": 9
}, {
  "a": 4,
  "b": 3,
  "c": 7
}, {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 0,
  "c": 6
}];

function clone(obj) {
  if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
  var copy = obj.constructor();
  for (var attr in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
  }
  return copy;
}
var temp = source.map(function(arr) {
  return clone(arr); //clone will make deep copy of the object
});
source[0].a = 50; //update the value from source object, it will not update `temp` array 
temp.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.a - b.a; // `.a` will be the `key` to be sorted
});
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(temp));
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(source));
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: *map* doesn't make a "deep" copy, `var temp = source.slice()` gives the same result and is less to type.

Comment: @RobG, I got that wrong ;) Have updated the code with helper `clone` and added some comments too! I hope I am correct this time. Thank you for correcting me..